# Should I display data using MVP and WPF through binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, mvp

I'm doing a paper on code-design and I'm comparing MV-C,P and VM to see which one is the best fit for WPF. During my research I realised that MVVM is the obvious choice cause of the databinding among other criterias.

Even If I know this I have to "prove" this in a sense so I'm creating an application both in MVP and MVVM that does exactly the same thing but handles code differently. With this I will explain the pros and cons with these code-patterns but in my creating with the MVP-application I reached a problem.

I have a model with the "buisness-logic" and my presenter creates a list of these model objects that my view can display.

My problem is how I display them

In MVVM I bind my list to a `ListBox` cause that is how MVVM is "made" to do.
EG

```
<Window.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:type model:Mymodel}">
    //Some DataTemplate Definition
  </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then binding to my `Listbox`

```
<ListBox ItemSources={Binding someProperty} />
```

**It's not fully coded but you get the gesture**

But if I've understood correctly, **binding** with MVP is not how it should be.

You should not bind anything in MVP cause that is not how it is supposed to work, or am I wrong here?

So if I shouldn't bind data, how can I display this list of my model objects in a `ListBox` so it doesn't say

```
Model Object
Model Object
Model Object
Model Object
```

**I understand that you should use MVVM for WPF but for the sake of proving why it's better I need to show how MVP can work in WPF also.**

Comment: Using WPF ( _personal opinion_ ) you should use bindings but since you've mentioned MVP I would bind to presenter which should be a bridge between View and Model.

Comment: And when you mean bind to presenter is it binding to functions in the presenter? Or properties? I don't think the presenter should contain properties?

Comment: From what I know you cannot bind to the method in WPF so you have to wrap methods with properties ... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using WPF, it is as you said made to work with MVVM, trough the data-binding. MVP was often used with Windows-form where no data-binding was available. If you want your applications to have the same functionality and use the same technology (WPF) you can't avoid using binding or it's at least more difficult to do. As long as you talk through the presenter to your model you're still using MVP. You can decide for yourself if you want to use

- **Passive View** - The presenter handles ALL dialog between the view and model
- **SuperVising Presenter** - The View knows about the model and the presenter handles "difficult-code" that is to much to be handled between the view and model.

If you're using binding I would say (Unsure about it) you're using **SuperVising Presenter** which is not "recommended", but using MVP in WPF is not recommended either so...

**EDIT Example**

For instance if you want to display a list you need to have an interface that has a property of a list containing objects you want to display.

```
public interface myinterface
{
  ObservableCollection<YourModel> ListName {get; set;}
}
```

and then in your presenter just "push" the data to that list

```
private myinterface _my;
public Presenter(myinterface my)
{ this._my = my;}

_my.ListName = // Add whatever Data you want into this list.
```

And in your view

```
<ListBox ItemSource ={Binding ListName}>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>Set how you want to display the list</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

This is a unclear example but hopefully can give you the idea how MVP works with WPF ( in a small way)

Comment: But then a presenter must use properties for it to be able to bind?

Comment: No (At least I have not encountered it). Everybinding is connected to your interface's property.

Comment: Added a example.

Comment: Thank you. This gave me some more clarification on my problem!

Comment: But why is it not recommended. This is exactly how I would implement my presentation layer. Compared to pure MVVM, this results in simpler XAML, more logic can be captured in C# and unit tested. Compare to pure MVP, this results in simpler presenter, and simpler IView interface.

Comment: It's not recommended cause WPF was created with MVVM in-mind. When using MVP the design pattern is, 1-View to 1-Presenter. But if you are using MVVM you can have multiple views to 1-ViewModel. More logic can be captured yes (Only if you're using **Passive View**), but it with MVVM you remove all code-behind, meaning that you can have people working with ViewModels( Code-logic) and have other people work with UI-design(The View,Presentation-logic) in theory.@XiaoguoGe

Comment: @Bojje The pattern I prefer, which is close to the example you have given, is Presenter manipulates the View through both myinterface and IView interface. This mixed pattern is superior to pure MVP because it utilizes WPF binding ability which makes the IView interface simpler. It is also superior than pure MVVM in that it makes the binding contract explicit(captured by myinterface). And makes the view thinner by making myinterface as close as possible to final display and removes all converters, triggers, multi-bindings.

Comment: @Bojie As to the reasons you have given, WPF is designed for MVVM does not mean we have to use pure MVVM. Multiple views one ViewModel does not have much use case in reality. MVP can capture more logic than MVVM in general. It doesn't matter what flavor of MVP it is. Even a MVVM view without codebehind can hind a lot of logic in XAML. The mixed model as is given in your example can separate design and development as well.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot add as much code as I want to the comment so I'll post an answer. If something is unclear just give me a feedback so I'll give you more details.

From the example you've shown I would go about and make binding from *View* to *Presenter* which should be the bridge between *View* and *Model* as you can see in here :
[image: MVP scheme from wikipedia]
*( Image from [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) )*

*View* should send events/changes to the presenter and presenter should be the "brain/logic" of the *View* which decides if it should update the *Model* or not.

---

Assuming you've the *View* like this one :

```
<UserControl x:Class="EntryNamespace.MeView"
    ... >

    <!-- ListItems should return collection of Presenters -->
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Elementcontent should be a property inside Presenter that returns value from Model -->
                <Button Content="{Binding ElementContent}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</UserControl>
```

You can create a *Presenter* like this one :

```
class Presenter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ListItemPresenter> ListItems
    {
        get { return GetItems(); }
        set { SetItems(value); }
    }

    ObservableCollection<ListItemPresenter> GetItems()
    {
        // private logic to retrieve `ListItemPresenter` collection from model

        var collection = new ObservableCollection<ListItemPresenter>();
        foreach(ListItem listItem in Model.Items)
            collection.Add(listItem.GetPresenter());

        return collection;
    }

    void SetItems(ObservableCollection<ListItemPresenter> objects)
    {
        // private logic to transfer `ListItemPresenter` collection to model
        // remember to call NotifyPropertyChanged("ListItems");

        Model.Items.Clear();
        foreach(ListItemPresenter presenter in objects)
            Model.Items.Add(presenter.GetModel());

        NotifyPropertyChanged("ListItems");
    }
}
```

You *Model* can look like this:

```
public class ListItem
{
    ListItemPresenter m_Presenter;

    public ListItemPresenter GetPresenter()
    {
        return m_Presenter;
    }

    string m_ElementContent;

    public string ElementContent
    {
        get { return m_ElementContent; }
        set { m_ElementContent = value; }
    }

    public ListItem(ListItemPresenter presenter)
    {
        m_Presenter = presenter;
    }
}
```

---

Another way to use *Presenter* can look like such :

Assuming you've similar *View* just create a *Presenter*:

```
public class Presenter
{
    ObservableCollection<ListItem> m_ListItems = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>(); 

    public ObservableCollection<List> ListItems
    {
        get { return m_ListItems; }
    }

    public Presenter(MeView view)
    { 
        Binding binding = new Binding("ListItems");
        binding.Source = ListItems;
        view.MeListView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
        // other view events, bindings etc.
    }
}
```

---

It's not the best way of communicating between *View* and *Model* indirectly, but should give you small hint. It will be up to you if you want to split your controls that each will have it's own *Presenter* or if you want one per window.

Comment: But this is just how MVVM would work. With MVP you should use an interface for each view and the presenter displays code through that interface. I appreciate the code, but this is more how MVVM works with WPF. Not MVP.

Comment: Yeah from what I've connected it's one-View-to-one-Presenter. Allowing it for "easy" or "fast" unit-testing ( I have not tried it yet). But from what you've giving I me I guess that you can't escape to use binding in WPF no matter what type of design-pattern you use?

Comment: It's hard to produce a good example here. I post my answers using my coffee break so I try to make everything very simple. You can get rid of the Binding and use something like `view.MeListView.ItemsSource = someItemsSource`. This is up to you how you handle it. I use binding because it's simple.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You gave me a good example but it wasn't so focused on MVP, more on MVVM. going to select Bojjes answer.